# How to filter combobox by textsearch input WIN32 API

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

I'm trying to filter my combobox by text input and hide other options that are not similar. I have been playing around with the combobox control messages but it doesn't hide other options in the combobox. I'm not sure what to do, I have read about WM_COMPAREITEM but I don't understand what to do with it. Please refer to the images below:

**How it is** vs                   **How I want it to be**

[image: How it is]        [image: How I want it to be]

```
void addFunc(HWND hwnd)
{
HWND hwndCombo;

CreateWindow(TEXT("static"), TEXT("Print size: "), WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,
    75, 10, 90, 25, hwnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
hwndCombo = CreateWindow(TEXT("combobox"), NULL, WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_VSCROLL | 
CBS_DROPDOWN | CBS_SORT,
    75, 35, 120, 110, hwnd, NULL, g_hinst, NULL);

SetWindowText(hwndCombo, items[4]);
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    SendMessage(hwndCombo, CB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)items[i]);
}
```

Comment: You might be looking for something along the lines of [Autocomplete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/bb776884(v=vs.85)).

Comment: If you want to do this with a combobox, you have to refill it with just the matching items every time the autocomplete list changes.  It's hacky and fiddly but I know of no other way.  `WM_COMPAREITEM` doesn't really come into it - that determines sort order in certain types of combobox, it doesn't filter what is displayed at all.

Comment: Perhaps you need to handle CBN_EDITCHANGE notifications of combobox.

Comment: @pau You really just need to [manually enable Autocomplete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/how-to-enable-autocomplete-manually). Depending on the desired behavior, there's a fair bit of code to write. A hack like constantly updating the combo box items isn't required, though.

Comment: @IInspectable So would that work with `CBS_DROPDOWN | CBS_OWNERDRAWFIXED`?  If so, neat!

Comment: I'm very new to this, although I understood the concept of Autocomplete, I just cant figure out how to implement this. Is there a sample code of autocomplete (a simple one) using winapi c++. I've tried googling everywhere but no luck.

Comment: @isetsdfse I suggest you could refer to the Docs: [Using Autocomplete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/ac-ovw) [IAutoComplete interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shldisp/nn-shldisp-iautocomplete)